# IDEA: Debugger skipping lines

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea

I am not sure what's going on here.

1. I set up a breakpoint.
2. I start code in debug mode.
3. Debugger jumps to the breakpoint
4. I `step over`
5. Debugger goes somewhere but the next line ...

Is this a known issue? Am i not using the tool correctly?

Here is an example:

**Debugger starts, we stop at the breakpoint.**

[image]

**Instead of going to the constructor of the class i asked to step into to (expect to get to line 29)**

[image]

**It's jumping to superclass automatically (!@$!#)**

[image]

**But then ... when i `step over` it skips lines ..**

I would like (when i `step over`) to go to the next line and when i `step in` to think less and do what it's told. Is this a configuration issue somewhere in my instance?

Comment: Can you show what lines are skipped? To jump into constructor use **Smart step into**, otherwise you'll go to the fields initialization which is invoked before the constructor.

Comment: For example, line 21 is never seen, line 24 is never seen. I did a complete 'make' and 'rebuild' but still issue persists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get behavior similar to Eclipse use `Run` | **Smart Step Into**, this will skip directly to the constructor ignoring any other executable code that can run before it. Note that **step over** will not step through lines that do not contain executable code (line #21).

While using keyboard shortcut is much faster, you can still add **Smart Step Into** action to the toolbar in `File` | `Settings` | **Menus and Toolbars**, **Main Toolbar**.

Comment: i have same problem in eclipse with c++ .how can i debug the code going line by line???